# Informatica Workflow Scheduling with Autosys

Tags: workflow, scheduling, informatica, autosys

**Informatica Workflow Scheduling with Autosys.**

I am trying to understand more about the Informatica Workflow Scheduling with Autosys.

Assume I have an Informatica workflow **wf_test** and a UNIX script say **test.sh** with pmcmd command to run this workflow. Also, I wrote a JIL 
**(test.jil)** for Autosys to schedule my test.sh. at daily 10:00 PM.

How exactly Autosys kick-off workflow wf_test at the specified schedule?

Can anyone shed some light about the communication between Autosys and Informatica?

Do we need to have both Informatica and Autosys server installed on the same server?

Is there any agent or service needs be present in-between Autosys and Informatica to happen this possible?

Additionally, can we directly give informatica details to Autosys without any script?

Many Thanks
aks

Answer (score 1):

> 1. How exactly Autosys kick-off workflow wf_test at the specified schedule?

Autosys is a scheduling tool. An autosys job keep checking every 5 seconds, if any job is scheduled to run, based on the jil. When the time comes and the condition satisfied, it will run the given command on the given host. It could be a pmcmd command or any shell script.

> 2. Can anyone shed some light about the communication between Autosys and Informatica?

The communication should be between Autosys Server and the server where Informatica is installed. Read this [article](http://www.krishnatraining.com/upload/Autosys-Job-Management-Unix-User-Guide%20(1).pdf). Additionally check if your autosys engineering team on steps to implement the same in your project/environment.

> 3. Do we need to have both Informatica and Autosys server installed on the same server?

Definately not. It should be separated. But the connectivity should be established.

> 4. Is there any agent or service needs be present in-between Autosys and Informatica to happen this possible?

Yes, Read the article given in point 2.

> 5. Additionally, can we directly give informatica details to Autosys without any script?

Yes. You can mentioned the whole pmcmd command.

Comment: NP @aks . Please check this [What to do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

As Autosys is scheduling tool , it will trigger command at specified time mentioned in the Job jil , the important part here is , we also mention the machine name where we want to execute that particular command.

So to answer your question, Autosys and Informatica can be on different servers , provided Autosys agent is configured on Informatica server and the Informatica machine/server details are configured in Autosys.(its like creating a machine on Autosys similiar to creating Global variable or a Job)

As we are running our workflows through shell scripts using pmcmd command , and not to mention Autosys and Informatica are on different servers, there might be way you can directly call Workflows from Autosys but that will make things complicated when you're working at large scale calling 1000s of workflows, Instead having a generic script to call pmcmd which can utilised by multiple workflows seems an easier option.

Answer (score 0):

All Autosys does is "run a command at a specified time" in this case. It's completely unaware of Informatica. It doesn't need to be on the same server as there simply is no communication between them.

All it needs, is the access to the `test.sh` script, wherever it is. And this, in turn, needs to be able to run the `pmcmd` utility. So in most basic setup, the Informatica >client< with the `pmcmd` could be on the same server with Autosys. Informatica Server just needs to be reachable to pmcmd.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to schedule the jobs using the in-built scheduler service,available from 10.x version. You don't have to even write a pmcmd command to trigger the workflow.